# Ember DRY pattern for reusing "Ember.computed.alias"

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have a form that transitions through several views. Currently each controller.js file has a long list of these `Ember.computed.alias`. How can I break that out into one file and import it into each controller?

Currently in each controller.js

```
entityEmail: Ember.computed.alias('controllers.checkout.entityEmail'),
entityDOB: Ember.computed.alias('controllers.checkout.entityDOB'),
entityPhone: Ember.computed.alias('controllers.checkout.entityPhone'),
entityAddress1: Ember.computed.alias('controllers.checkout.entityAddress1'),
entityAddress2: Ember.computed.alias('controllers.checkout.entityAddress2'),
entityCity: Ember.computed.alias('controllers.checkout.entityCity'),
```

I would like to pull all that out into a file so I can simply import some  1 liner in each controller.js

Answer (score 2):

This is a classic use-case for [Ember.Mixin](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Mixin.html).
You can extract all these computed props into a single mixin and extend every controller (that needs to have these props) with it.

Add the following mixin to your app

```js
// app/mixins/entity-form.js

import Ember from 'ember';

const { Mixin, inject, computed: { alias } } = Ember;

export default Mixin.create({

  checkout: inject.controller(),

  entityEmail: alias('checkout.entityEmail'),
  entityDOB: alias('checkout.entityDOB'),
  entityPhone: alias('checkout.entityPhone'),
  entityAddress1: alias('checkout.entityAddress1'),
  entityAddress2: alias('checkout.entityAddress2'),
  entityCity: alias('checkout.entityCity')

});
```

And then use it in a controller

```js
// app/controllers/example.js

import EntityFormMixin from 'yourAppName/mixins/entity-form';

const { Controller } = Ember;

export default Controller.extend(EntityFormMixin, {
  // rest of controller's props and functions
});
```

Note: [Ember.inject API](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.inject.html) is available since [Ember 1.10.0](http://emberjs.com/blog/2015/02/07/ember-1-10-0-released.html#toc_injected-properties). In case you are using an older version you need to replace the inject line with: `needs: ['checkout']` and prefix the aliases with `"controllers."` like you did in your example.